# A random perturbation of a distance matrix

Tags: matrix, distance

Let $A=(d_{ij})$ be a distance matrix, i.e.,

1. $d_{ii}=0$ for all $i$
2. $d_{ij}>0$ for all $i\neq j$
3. $d_{ij}=d_{ji}$ for all $i,j$
4. $d_{ij}+d_{jk}\geq d_{ik}$ for all $i,j,k$

How to find a random distance matrix $A'$ close to $A$ (by any matrix norm)?

Comment: Please explain your statistical application.  That will help us understand what you might mean by "random," which otherwise is too vague.  After all, scaling all distances by any random positive value (using any distribution at all) will yield a "random distance matrix" and, by making that positive value likely to lie in a tiny neighborhood of $1,$ will yield a close matrix in any norm -- but that trivial construction seems unlikely to be of much use in any practical setting.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I need a sample of distance matrices close to a given one to construct a training set for SVM.

Comment: Where does the distance matrix come from?  If it's computed from a set of points, why not just perturb those points?

Comment: @whuber good idea, and if it's not available for some reason, we can use MDS to get one "close" to it and perturb that.

Comment: @John Yes, but I am concerned such perturbations could be meaningless.  For instance, if the MDS space has a smaller dimension than the original, then the perturbations will be artificially constrained.  That doesn't mean your idea is bad or unworkable -- it's a natural approach -- but it throws a cautionary light on it.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your idea and your comments. My idea was to permute the points to get a distance matrix $B$ and then to put $A'=k(A+\epsilon B)$ for appropriate $k$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: @John Madden Thanks for your idea.

Comment: That idea is risky, because $A^\prime$ is not necessarily a distance matrix, even within arbitrarily small neighborhoods of $0$ (for $\epsilon$). Consider the case $A=\pmatrix{0&1&2\\1&0&1\\2&1&0}$ (the distance matrix for the points $(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)$) and $B=\pmatrix{0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0}$ (the distance matrix for an equilateral triangle).  When $\epsilon \lt 0,$ $A+\epsilon B$ is not a distance matrix because it does not satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. I forgot to mention the assumption $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: One can take $\epsilon$ to be small positive, $k$ to be a bit less than 1 and add other permuted distance matrices if necessary.

Comment: @whuber The problem with my data is that the distances are not in an euclidean space. Thus the distance matrix $C$ obtained from MDS is quite far from the original matrix. But then I can take $A'=(1-\epsilon)A+\epsilon C$ for a small $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Not being Euclidean would not appear to be any problem at all: you can still perturb your data.

Comment: @whuber But then the distance matrix obtained from MDS may be far away from the original matrix.

Comment: You lost me.  I am referring to *data,* not MDS.  I don't see any reference to MDS in your question.

Comment: @whuber Sorry. The point is that I can't perturb the original points, I don't know their locations. I can perturb only the distance matrix obtained from MDS.

Comment: Okay.  Because you describe it as a *Euclidean* distance matrix, that means there exists a set of points in some finite-dimensional Euclidean space that realizes this matrix *without error.*  Why not just find such a set of points and perturb them?

Comment: @whuber Sorry, my bad. The space is not Euclidean, just metric.